# Change self of parent class to subClass

Tags: python, class, self

i have a structure like,

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value=True):
        if value:
            Bar()
        else:
            Zoo()
    pass

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

class Zoo(Foo):
    pass




z = Foo(True)  # instance of Foo() class
```

when i instantiate the class `Foo()` it will return the instance of `Foo` class, but i want it should return the instance of `Bar` or `Zoo` class(ie. any class which is called according to the value supplied to Foo class)

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what `__new__()` is for:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls, value=True):
        if cls != Foo:
            return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls)
        elif value:
            return super(Foo, cls).__new__(Bar)
        else:
            return super(Foo, cls).__new__(Zoo)

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

class Zoo(Foo):
    pass

z = Foo(True)  # instance of Bar() class
```

Comment: What's the point of using `__new__()` when you could just use a function?

Comment: @phant0m Why can't they be both valid?

Comment: My intent was just to provide an alternative. The difference has more "informational/documentatory character".

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer I'm not saying it isn't. It just seems a bit over the top ;) -- glglgl: In retrospect, I should have worded it a bit nicer, I didn't mean it to sound that harsh.

Comment: 1. Compare `type(your_foo)` and `type(m_Foo)`. Besides, I can call my class `Foo`, while yours is a function and should be named `foo`. Maybe this might not be wanted...

Comment: `Zoo()` will now yield a `Bar` instance, because the `value` parameter is set to `True` by default.

Comment: Hmm, right. Maybe the approach should be refined even more - or dumped altogether in favour of the function approach.

Comment: I just changed the way `__new__` acts.

Comment: Thanks i just saw the post noW. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Just use a function:

```
def foo(value=True):
    if value:
        return Bar()
    else:
        return Zoo()
```

There is no need for a class, because you only ever want to create instances from two *other* classes. Thus, you can just use a function to select between the two.

This is often called a factory.

---

If you want to be able to supply custom arguments to the initializer, you can use this:

```
def foo(value=True):
    if value:
        return Bar
    else:
        return Zoo
```

and call it like this:

```
z = foo(True)(params for Bar/Zoo)
```

Comment: @Wooble my mistake I checked it with `__init__`.

Comment: Presumably OP actually wants `Bar` and `Zoo` to have a common superclass and the real usecase isn't as trivial as the example.

Comment: @Wooble Ah I didn't notice the inheritance. But still, he can just use a function as a factory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer of factory function, but i need the inheritance structure. Any other way, will __new__ help?

Comment: @ProgramQuestions This works with inheritance. You just call `foo` instead of `Foo`.